# Rocket league offline multiplayer with KB+M and Xbox one controller

Tags: pc, controllers, rocket-league

I'm trying to play Rocket League with KB+M and xbox one controller, I've looked online and it seems it is possible with the xbox 360 controller.
The way it's described is, start rocket league, disconnect and connect the controller until it shows that it's player 2.
That only seems to work with xbox 360 controllers.

Any tips to make it work with the xbox one controller?

Comment: just an idea, have you tried pressing start on the controller after starting up rocket league? also try this without disconnecting the controller while ingame, as this could lead to it not being detected. Which is your primary input device, i.e. if you leave both connected at startup and enter a game, with which one can you control the car?